# Iframe proxying without extra traffic

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

For the sake of cross-domain javascript communications I use iframe proxying technique with onresize event monitoring
(the method is well known and perfectly described here http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes).
But I'm still not happy because of extra page load produced by the hidden iframe.
How to get rid of this unwanted iframe traffic?

Comment: What do you want to do  - send messages from one domain to another or... ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 Full days of constructive research. Don't do the same mistake as me-- it was a waste of time.

[Yet Another cross-domain iframe resize Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5908676/706363)