# Pass value from iframe to parent of different domain or port

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I want to Pass value from iframe to parent of different domain and port , can  i do that if yes than how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you require [postMessage](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-html-5-postmessage)

Answer (score 0):

see if this post helps

[Yet Another cross-domain iframe resize Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908676/yet-another-cross-domain-iframe-resize-question)