# Get parentWindow value in iframe

Tags: window, parent

I am having two web applicaion in java running different JBOSS Server.

Like

- App1 - http:\10.20.34.55:8080\SpringApp1
- App2 - http:\10.20.34.55:8089\SpringApp2

I am using iFrame in App1 to get the App2 UI details.

```
<iframe src="http:\\10.20.34.55:8089\SpringApp2" ></iframe>
```

I am able get the App2 application in App1. When I do some changes in App2 with in App1 it's perfoming well.

```
App1 - Parent Window
App2 - Child Window
```

Please help me when I am doing some operation in App2-child window, I have to autosubmit App1.

I am using this code but no use.

```
parent.document.getElementById("App1Submit").click();
```

App1Submit - App1 submit button.

Answer (score 0):

[Yet Another cross-domain iframe resize Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5908676/706363)

I did extensive research into how to communicate via iframes, that is cross domain- but it offers a variety of methods and explanations.

You should consider searching the forum first for relevant answers or questions.

**I would also strongly recommend using and learning a bit of [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) to enhance your experience in managing HTML. jQuery does all the hard work for you and is very flexible.**