# iframe to auto-adjust height, without modification of framed page?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, same-origin-policy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Yet Another cross-domain Iframe resize question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908676/yet-another-cross-domain-iframe-resize-question)

If I have a webpage with an iframe that is including a page from a different domain name, how can I prevent a situation where there are two scrollbars, one for the contents of the iframe and one for the contents of the outer page?

Ideally I want the automatically adjust to the contents of the iframe, is that possible?

Note that I only want to make changes to the outer page, and not to the inner iframed page. If this can only be done on select browsers, I would be interested to know.

Comment: Duplicate -- in short, though, the answer is "no".