# is it possible to Change the width/height of an iframe from within

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, iframe

I am going to host my app in a site. The app will be shown inside an iframe in it. 
i need my app to be on full screen, is there anyway where I can change the size of that iframe which will hold my app from my application?? 
My app and the site hosting it are not the same domain.

```
$("iframe", window.parent.document).css("width", "1000px");
```

this is not working as the site and app do not belong to same domain

Comment: I think you'll find this quite hard if they are not on the same domain. Not to mention this is frowned upon!!

Comment: You need to use `attr('width', '1000px')` I think. But it will work only if iframe belong to the same domain.

Comment: @Neurofluxation Yes i am not able to change my app to full screen mode

Comment: @jcubic I tried it too !! it didn't work

Comment: @vignesh - if you require a more definitive answer. This isn't possible. Not without a nasty X-Domain hack

Comment: @Neurofluxation oh :( I thought since its just a client side change I can do it easily :( like how we inspect element and modify the width height via browsers

Comment: Afraid not, here's a more fully fledged answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908676/yet-another-cross-domain-iframe-resize-qa

Comment: Suddenly got two downvotes :D
Downvoters please care to comment so that I can improve my question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sanest way, if your app needs to run full screen, is to break out of the iframe. That is, detect if your page is in an iframe, and if so, redirect the browser to your page so that is is no longer in the iframe!

[This page](http://usablelayout.com/articles/automatically-break-out-iframe) explains how to do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (top.location!= self.location) {
        top.location = self.location.href;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This kind of negates the whole point of the question, which is to resize the iframe.

Comment: @Neurofluxation But the question was already answered. It was "no". So the OP will have to look into other ways of achieving what they want (which is, show the app full screen). See my answer as a "Plan B", or a last ditch effort.

Comment: I'll let you off then ;) Voted back up for explanation. Apologies!!

Answer (score 2):

If you control both pages then you can use HTML5 Post message:

outside:

```
$(window).bind("message", function(e) {
    $('iframe').attr({
        width: e.originalEvent.data.width,
        height: e.originalEvent.data.height
    });
});
```

inside:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    parent.postMessage({width: '200px', height: '200px'}, 'http://localhost');
});
```

Comment: No I dont have the control of it !!  is there anyother way to change it?? 
thanks and +1 for the answer