# Iframe Cross domain communication - resize event - cross browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-browser, cross-domain

When the main `Window` wants to send message to a child Iframe -

It sets the child's Iframe url to its *current* url+ hash (which represents data).

> But how would the iframe get's the new data ?

We have 4 options :  *( i'm not talking about new api's eg `postMessaage` nor XDM libraries)*

- The child is polling the new hash ( setTimeout)
- The main window can resize the iframe  (the iframe must register `onResize`)
- The OnHashChange Event can be used on the iframe
- Destroying/creating proxy Iframe which uses "onload" to send msg (javascript function !) to its "SameDomainIframe" via `parent.frames['samedonain'].sendData(...)`

Here comes my question : (regarding option#2 ( resize event) ):

According to [**this**](http://help.dottoro.com/ljorlllt.php) article :

> In Firefox, Opera, Google Chrome and Safari, the onresize event is
>   fired only when the size of the browser window is changed. In Internet
>   Explorer, the onresize event is fired when the size of the browser
>   window or an element is changed.

**Question :**

Is there any cross browser solution for this resize thing ?

I don't want a situation where a user resize the browser , and the iframe will re-read the data !

I want the data to be read Only when I send a message to the iframe and **manually** resize it

Comment: _“We have 2 options”_ – we also have [option 3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onhashchange) …

Comment: @CBroe Totally agree.

Comment: @CBroe There is another one./edited.

Comment: So why are you so focused on the resize method?

Comment: @CBroe Cuz it's much simpler than dealing with another proxy iframe  , and OnHashChange is IE8+. Also polling is the worst solution ever. and I want to know this topic with all its aspects. I like this cross domain topic very much. it all started when i [read this article](http://ternarylabs.com/2011/03/27/secure-cross-domain-iframe-communication/) which uses the onresize.

Comment: _“Also polling is the worst solution ever”_ – well then I’d use that as the fallback for the _worst browsers ever_ only :-) Set up polling as default, then see if hashChange is available (by provoking it directly after initialization), and if so, cancel the polling.

Comment: _“I don't want a situation where a user resize the browser , and the iframe will re-read the data !”_ – also don’t see why that would be so bad – just _reading_ the data should not be that expensive, as long as you don’t _process_ that data if it’s still the same as hen it was read the last time.

Comment: OK. still - What about the Onresize for iframe ? which browser supports that event ? couldnt find it.

Comment: Well, an iframe is an instance of `window` itself, so basically it should support the resize event in the same way. But you can simple [test it](http://jsfiddle.net/TW6t7/) with a range of (legacy) browsers you want to support.

Comment: @CBroe ( resize my baby lol). well the problem with jsfiddle is that you cant test it with ie8/7. well i put the code on a pure html test. tnx.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot jsfiddle does not work well with older IE – try http://fiddle.jshell.net/TW6t7/show/light/, that’s just the result document without anything around it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38768/discussion-between-royi-namir-and-cbroe)

Comment: you can memorize the browser window dimensions and throw away duplicates in the resize event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use porthole which is a cross browser proxy script for iframes you will need to be able to host a small proxy file on the receiving end of the other iframe though.  You can then pass information and events from one iframe to another across browsers and domains

http://ternarylabs.github.io/porthole/