# Iframe not working when i am using absolute URL

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Please check below my code -

```
<script>
function autoResize(myiframe){
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;
    if(document.getElementById){
        newheight=document.getElementById(myiframe).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
        newwidth=document.getElementById(myiframe).contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
    }
    document.getElementById(myiframe).height= (newheight+20) + "px";
    document.getElementById(myiframe).width= (newwidth) + "px";
}

</script>



 <iframe id="myiframe" src="http://www.learnphp.in" width="100%" onload="autoResize('myiframe')"></iframe>
```

I have changes this code but working fine when i am using Relative path(internal page) such as `files/test.html`, `mypage.html` etc. But it is not working for the absolute path(external page) like `http://www.learnphp.in`

Please suggest me how can i show external page auto height in my iframe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yet Another cross-domain iframe resize Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908676/yet-another-cross-domain-iframe-resize-qa)

Answer (score 0):

Learn about the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

It prevents you from reading the contents of other domains. If you have control over the other domain, you need to use [post message](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) and have code on both domains.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have control over the URL you are using then you cannot use this URL and it is because of "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" response header. This option prevents the browser from displaying iFrames that are not hosted on the same domain as the parent page.

If you want to use any specific service from that URL then use its API(if available). Or you can simply use  to route to that particular page.