# integrate angularjs applications without iframe

Tags: angularjs, html, iframe

I'd like to integrate an external angularjs application in another one. I'm currently using iframe to integrate the external one in order to let it keep it's one context. But i'm not like because i have frame sizing issue with header and footer and scrollbar...

Is there another way to integration and external app without iframe? How would this external app maintain it's context (internal link, css, js...) then?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can resize the iframe to adapt its content size. You can read more about it in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908676/yet-another-cross-domain-iframe-resize-qa)

Comment: Thanks @Julien, I'll explore your references