# postMessage with Sharepoint iframe resize not working correctly

Tags: javascript, iframe, sharepoint, postmessage

I have a problem trying to resize an iframe inside a Sharepoint environment through Cross Domain. I've tried a bunch of solutions found on the net and nothing works except Baker Humadi's solution near the end about postMessage:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15558627/2171556

I added a Script Editor to the Sharepoint page with the following (My iframe URL is of course pointing to my child page):

```
<script>
// Create IE + others compatible event handler
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

// Listen to message from child window
eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
    document.getElementById('frame').height = e.data + 'px';
},false);
</script>

<iframe id="frame" src="childpage" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

On the child page I've included the following (RestSection is being populated by some other means so please ignore content in this post):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function()
{
    var actual_height = document.getElementById('RestSection').scrollHeight;
    parent.postMessage(actual_height,"childpage"); 
    //* allows this to post to any parent iframe regardless of domain
}
</script>

<div id="RestSection">
    //List of things
</div>
```

When I am editing the code snippet in Sharepoint it is actually resizing the page as it should. When I Check In it stops working and I've noticed the height is set quite strange - perhaps some postMessage object?:

```
<iframe id="frame" src="childpage" scrolling="no" height="{"command":"RequestSuccess","requestIndex":1,"result":null}px"></iframe>
```

I don't understand why it works when I am editing the page in Sharepoint but suddenly does'nt when I check it In. Has anyone seen this behaviour before or could in some way enlighten me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should ask for help here is the SharePoint subsite https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ .A script that works in edit mode but not in view is a common fail.